# Distribute CSS with a React component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, npm, software-distribution

I have a React component `index.js` which has styling in `style.css`.

I want to distribute this component on `npm`, but I am confused about how I can make it easy for other developers to use the styling.

There are three options I have seen:

- Use `require('./style.css')` and rely on the users having a bundling solution (e.g. `webpack`, `rollup`). I don't like this solution as it forces users down a certain route to use my component.
- Make the user import the style with `<link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/package/style.css" />`. I don't like this solution as it means that my users will have to make changes to their HTML rather than just including the React component where they want it.
- Put the CSS in the component itself with a plugin such as [react-jss](https://github.com/cssinjs/react-jss). This isn't a viable solution for me as I have a large number of SCSS files making up the styling for my component.

None of these solutions meet my needs and make it quite awkward to use my component. How can I distribute the component so that it's easy for people to use it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let the users choose how to include the file in their app. I'd suggest to add to your `README.md`:

> Don't forget to include the CSS file!
>
> Using ES6 with a module bundler like Webpack:
>
> ```
> import 'package/dist/style.css';
> ```
>
> Or, in plain old reliable HTML:
>
> ```
> <!DOCTYPE HTML>
> <html>
>  <head>
>    ...
>    <link href="node_modules/package/dist/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
>    ...
>  </head>
>  ...
> </html>
> ```
>
> You can also use your own style.

This is the approach taken by most packages:

- [React Bootstrap](http://react-bootstrap.github.io)
- [Blueprint](http://blueprintjs.com/)
- [React Dates](http://airbnb.io/react-dates/)
- [React Tags Input](https://github.com/olahol/react-tagsinput)
- etc.

Comment: I do the same for [React-Table](https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table).  Works very well as long as you let your user know that they need to include it.

Answer (score 2):

To extend from GG's answer an advanced version would be to add js version of the css file.

Because this

```
import 'package/dist/style.css';
```

requires users to have Webpack configured to load css which might not be the case. For example I rarely do because I use css-in-js tools for my styling needs.

Instead if you wrap the css file into something like this:

`package/dist/style.js`

```
var insertCss = require('insert-css'); // https://github.com/substack/insert-css
// inline the whole style.css here
insertCss(".YourComponent { color: blue }");
```

Then the users can just do

```
import 'package/dist/style';
```

and it will work always with any module loader (Webpack, Browserify, Rollup...) regardless of their configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest including the css file on npm, and documenting those alternatives.

- Those who prefer to use css as css can duplicate the stylesheet
- Those who prefer to use build tools can do the require